# C++ templates to Java Generics

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

How to write this piece of code in Java. What happens in C++ code when it extends from array and how to make something looks like it in Java. What way must I choose. Maybe I must make a class and extend from it or maybe something else?

```
template <typename T1, size_t N>
class tensor : public array<T1,N> {};
```

Comment: There are ways around the problem that arrays cannot be derived from, but there is no way to emulate C++ integer template arguments (i.e. your `N`) with Java generics.

Comment: What does this piece of code extend exactly? the objects in array? or the array? Maybe to use Java generics is not good idea in this situation? I must solve this. It's the question of honor became now)

Comment: @AndrewKolenteew Eg. `std::array<int, 123>` is a class which represents an array of 123 `int`. (Problem 1: Java generics can't take values like 123). It can be used like normal arrays (`int arr[123]`), ie. accessing elements with `[index]` etc. (Problem 2: Java classes can't emulate `[]`), and/but it offers additional stuff not directly possible with raw arrays as class methods. Your class inherits from `std::array`, both type and size still unspecified, and probably adds some more methods.

Comment: (and that it's "not a good idea", and completely impossible, with Java generics, was said often enough now. I'm out too)

Comment: thanks, now you answered my question. I'll look for another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all. Java generics are less powerful compared to C++ templates.

There is simply no way to express such a template in Java.

Comment: So I must to find the other way to realise this code. What can you advice me?

Comment: ...and something like `std::array` doesn't exist too. Normal Java arrays can't be parent classes (and classes with arrays inside can't have `[]` etc.) You can't realize this code. Describe what it is good for, then we can suggest something else.

Comment: Sorry, **can't** be, not "can be"

Comment: There is no simple answer to such a question. I would advise you to study Java generics and collections first; then try to design something; and maybe then put that either on codereview.stackexchange.com ... or if you have specific questions, come back here. But dont expect other people to do be helpful with such open, generic requests.

Comment: @deviantfan Dont apologize; just edit your comment while you still can.

Comment: @Jägermeister I did already (but someone read it already and upvoted)

Comment: I know Java generics and collections I don't know C++ templates. I know that C++ templates more powerful than Java Generics. I also know that we cannot extend arrays in Java. I came here to get advice how to write such construction in Java. So I haven't heard anything helpful till this moment. If anybody wants to prove something I don't think that it's a good place for it.

Comment: @AndrewKolenteew If you knew all that, why do you ask in the first place? Repeat: `Describe what it is good for, then we can suggest something else.` Context.

Comment: I agree. You made this a Java question. If the whole point is to understand the template stuff; then why didnt you make it a question about templates with c++ tag on it only?!

Comment: @deviantfan I'll try to ask question another way, let me think a little)

Comment: @Jägermeister because my task is to write C++ program in Java.

Comment: `because my task is to write C++ program in Java` Uh... well. Whoever gave you this task, please stop believing that he/she knew something about programming.

Comment: @deviantfan customer whenever is right. My job is to make task.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Final comment; doesnt make much sense to continue from here: when asked to translate an application from language A to B ... sometimes bottom-up works (by simply rephrasing concept X to the concept the other language has). But if that isnt the case ... then do as we told you: understand the requirements behind the application, and rebuild them using Java. And tell your customer that isnt so easy as he imagines it to be. I hope you are paid by the hour though.